# I'm trying to enter multiple values from an android activity to firebase Realtime database,but the button in the code dont work

Tags: android, firebase, button, firebase-realtime-database

I have already written code for inserting values into database.
button name is **advbtn**
Button does not respond to click.How to make it work?

```
    public void Advbtn(View view) //code for button
           {

            ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                getvalues();
                ref.child("user").setValue(advposts);
                Toast.makeText(Advpost.this,"Posted successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError)
            {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have also declared classes for making a table in the database and called it in this program.

Comment: can you please describe better your problem and provide more code?, what is getvalues() ? please post the code

Comment: have you tried without the method ? just yourbutton.setOnClickListener.....

Comment: and how you are accesing this value advposts , can you provide the code to it too ?

Comment: http://www30.zippyshare.com/v/Fk5jHo22/file.html   Please visit this link for my entire code

Answer (score -2):

you have to use
yourbutton.setonClickListner(New OnClickLisnter) method

your method mainly use for starting a new activity..

Comment: Thank you,will try to use setonclick Listener for the button